# Continue after exception is thrown from a 2D array

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I'm building the model for a [Lights Out](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lights_Out_(game)) game I'm making and I keep running into a problem creating a method called I've named `flipSwitch`. The code below flips on or off the specified box but if I click on a box that is on the border, it throws a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException since it can't turn off a box that is outside the 2D array's limits.

I've tried using a `try-catch` block with nothing in the catch but then it won't try to turn off the rest of the boxes even if they exist. And I've also tried putting `continue;` in the catch but it gives me the error that says, "continue cannot be used outside of a loop."

In other words, how can I continue in my code and basically ignore the exceptions that are thrown? The picture below shows what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image]

```
private int[][] grid = new int[5][5];

public void flipSwitch(int row, int col)
    {
        if(getState(row, col) == ON){
            grid[row][col] = OFF;
            grid[row+1][col] = OFF;
            grid[row-1][col] = OFF;
            grid[row][col+1] = OFF;
            grid[row][col-1] = OFF;
        }else{
            grid[row][col] = ON;
            grid[row+1][col] = ON;
            grid[row-1][col] = ON;
            grid[row][col+1] = ON;
            grid[row][col-1] = ON;
        }
        clickCount++;
    }
```

Comment: It would be much easier and cleaner if you create a method like `switch(int row, int col, boolean status)` which first checks if `row` and `col` are in bound and then sets the status. Then call that method for each single cell you like to "switch".

Comment: @Tom That should be an answer. I for one would upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make this work with "ignoring an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`" you would need a `try/catch` for each `grid[..][..] = ..` line:

```
try { grid[row][col] = OFF; } catch (Exception e) {};
try { grid[row+1][col] = OFF; } catch (Exception e) {};
try { grid[row-1][col] = OFF; } catch (Exception e) {};
try { grid[row][col+1] = OFF; } catch (Exception e) {};
try { grid[row][col-1] = OFF; } catch (Exception e) {};
```

and as you can see, it looks horrible.

It would be much better (and cleaner) to write the following method:

```
private void switchState(int row, int col, int status) {
    if (/* check if 'row' is in bound */ && /* check if 'col' is in bound */) {
        grid[row][col] = status;
    }
}
```

And then call it like:

```
switchState(row, col, OFF);
switchState(row + 1, col, OFF);
switchState(row - 1, col, OFF);
switchState(row, col + 1, OFF);
switchState(row, col - 1, OFF);
```

This avoids the exception in the first place and is a bit easier to maintain. You can also use a different name, if you like :D.